# How to mail a specific sheet in a spreadsheet with selected column as .XLSX file?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet and I want to use Google App Script to auto send email with attachment is one sheet of the spreadsheet in .XLSX file. I can do it with the showed code below, but I do not know how to send this  sheet with like only columns from "A" to "F" for example. I've searched but still can not find a way, so please help me with this. Thank guys

```
function getSheetID(name){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(name)
 var sheetID = ss.getSheetId().toString() 
 return sheetID
}
function getGoogleSpreadsheetAsExcel(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var shID = getSheetID("SHE");
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?format=xlsx&gid="+shID;
    var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

    blob.setName("SHE.xlsx");

    MailApp.sendEmail("test@gmail.com", "Test  send only one sheet of whole spreadsheet", "Hi Ted, I", {attachments: [blob]});

  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send the active sheet as an email attachment from google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282117/send-the-active-sheet-as-an-email-attachment-from-google-sheets)

Comment: Would it be acceptable to send as a CSV instead of XLSX?